# CouchDB vs mongodb

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo, couchdbkit

We are developing application for which we going to use a NoSql database. We have evaluated couchdb and mongodb. Our application is in python and read-speed is most critical for our application. And application is reading a large number of documents.

I want ask:

1. Is reading large number of documents is faster in bson than json?
2. Which is better when we want to read say 100 documents, parse them & print result: python+mongodb+pymongo or python+couchdb+couchdbkit (database going to be on ec2 & accessible over internet)?

Answer (score -1):

1. bson
2. Try LogoDb from 1985 logo programming language for trs-80